# How to add SSL Encryption to my http rest server on Spray

Tags: scala, ssl, encryption, client-server, spray

I'm building a http rest server on spray that routes Post Requests and I want to make it encrypted with ssl.
This is the example from official spray webstie i used to builed the server and i want to change it to be with ssl : 
https://github.com/spray/spray-template/tree/on_spray-can_1.3/src/main/scala/com/example.

I have read here : http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-can/http-server/#ssl-support
That i need to add ServerSSLEngineProvider Parameter to Http.Bind (its in the Boot.scala in example git above ) . But i don't know how to build right the  ServerSSLEngineProvider  and what to give it .

```
IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 81 , ServerSSLEngineProvider = ???)
```

My question is what i need to put insted of the ??? here so my server will be ssl secured .

Thanks to the helpers.

Comment: Long story short - never expose Java process directy to the network. I would suggest to use ```nginx```, that can secure connections, perform load balancing and request filtering much faster and more reliable rather that Spray framework.